# Do i need to Dispose or Delete RestSharp Request before executing another Request

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, desktop-application, restsharp

Using RestSharp I want to use a webservice from a Windows Forms application using C# to make a desktop application.

I am getting a response from the first request,
but when I send another request I get a timeout error.
this is the code

```
client = new RestClient();

client.BaseUrl = "webservicelink";

client.Authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator("usrnm", "pswd");

var request = new RestRequest();

request.AddParameter("key",JVP8xGk4hsX2cZd0L3NQwYbI0mf4exPiSoAhVYnz");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check that the response is valid, and save the cookie for the next request.
Something like this might work:

```
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && response.StatusCode !=   HttpStatusCode.Created)
{
     throw new Exception(response.Content);
}
RestResponseCookie cookie = response.Cookies[0];

var anotherRequest = new RestRequest();
anotherRequest.AddCookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
anotherRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/xml");
...
IRestResponse anotherResponse = client.Execute(anotherRequest);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: it's giving error :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
at the line
     RestResponseCookie cookie = response.Cookies[0];